# how to get count of files in a remote machine in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to take the count of files in a remote machine.i used these codes:

**1st method:**

```
System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
```

**2nd method:**

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
```

using these am getting the file count,but its taking very much time.(eg:my remote machine containing more than 50000 records and its taking more than 3-4 minuts). i need a better solution through which i will get the count even more faster.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a .Net remoting method that would require a c# server on your remote machine (c# remoting is like rmi in java or RPC in C) you can find out more about c# remoting here http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/72x4h507%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.

I Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

Try Following

```
Directory.GetFiles("\\\\RemoteMachine\\ShareName").Length;
```

you may also try Linq

```
var fileCount = (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "file format", 
                 SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                 select file).Count();
```